# React-native bottom navigation with stacknavigator

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native and trying to learn. but I couldn't do what I wanted to do.

I have Tab Navigations and I want to Open Stack when I click the button. But I can't figure out how to do it, thanks in advance for your help.

[Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@mesutuca/screen-options-with-nested-navigators-%7C-react-navigation)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View,Text,TouchableOpacity,Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Home() {
  return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Home Page</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FeedScreen')}
      />
    </View>
 );
}

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
     <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Details} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function Details() {
  return <View><Text>Details</Text></View>;
}


function Profile() {
  return <View>
  <Text>Profile</Text>
  </View>;
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tabs can take a StackNavigator as the component and by default it will go to the first screen in that stack when you press the tab.

edit to your code

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View,Text,TouchableOpacity,Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function Home() {
  return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
     <Text>Home Page</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('FeedScreen')}
      />
    </View>
 );
} 
function Details() {
  return <View><Text>Details</Text></View>;
}


function Profile() {
  return <View>
  <Text>Profile</Text>
  </View>;
}

function FeedScreen() {
  return (
     <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Feed" component={FeedScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The `navigation.navigate(...)` part becomes a little more complicated but not too bad. See the example [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/). This one is basically opposite of your setup where the tabs are nested within a stack navigator.

Comment: your code is not working? Can you upload "snack"?